# jQuery UI Slider on Multiple Inputs not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Im a little stuck and wondering if anyone can spot why? its actually not generating the sliders at all so a little lost.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DmDkp/

HTML

```
<div class="markup scoreSlide">
    <input type="text" id="" class="scoreID" value="" />
    <div class="scoreSlider"></div> 
</div>

<div class="markup scoreSlide">
    <input type="text" id="" class="scoreID" value="" />
    <div class="scoreSlider"></div> 
</div>

<div class="markup scoreSlide">
    <input type="text" id="" class="scoreID" value="" />
    <div class="scoreSlider"></div> 
</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.scoreSlide').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.scoreID').slider({
            animate: true,
            range: "min",
            value: value: jQuery('.scoreID').val(),
            min: 1,
            max: 5,
            step: 1,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
             jQuery(this).find('.scoreSlider').html(ui.value);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what is this? `value: value: jQuery('.scoreID').val(),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(this).find('.scoreSlider').slider({
            animate: true,
            range: "min",
            value: jQuery('.scoreSlider').val(),
            min: 1,
            max: 5,
            step: 1,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
             jQuery(this).find('.scoreID').html(ui.value);
            },
        });
```

DEMO `-- >` http://jsfiddle.net/DmDkp/8/

To Get Values on textbox, do like this:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).parent().find('.scoreID').val(ui.value);
 }
```

Comment: Maybe i got it a little wrong, the slider is meant to be under the input? but seems its not.

Comment: i have updated here again: http://jsfiddle.net/DmDkp/5/ and change slider to change but not updating value, can you see why?